# Matplot lib won't plot all values in my dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary, matplotlib

I am using python and matplotlib to make a graph. The graph is working fine, here's a picture of it below.

[My Graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gNRFw.jpg)

However, I am having trouble plotting a second set of data on top of this. I just want to plot vertical lines corresponding to the values of a dictionary that I have called "F_type", which contains 15 items. I attempt to do this by using this code:

```
F_type = {'CaII': 3933.70, 'CaII': 3968.50, 'H': 3970.10, 'H': 4101.70, 'HeI': 4121.00, 'SiII': 4128.00, 'SiII': 4131.00, 'CaI': 4227.00, 'FeI': 4299.00, 'FeI': 4303.00, 'H': 4340.50, 'CH': 4314.00, 'MgII': 4481.00, 'H': 4861.30, 'H': 6562.70}

for keys, values in F_type.items():
    plt.axvline(x=values)
```

However, the resulting plot only shows 8 of the 15 values.

[It looks like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T2uGr.jpg)

Why isn't matplotlib plotting every value in the dictionary?

Comment: @ Easton Bornemeier that just gives me TypeError: 'float' object is not iterable

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Python doesn't allow keys that are exactly the same.

For instance:

```
>>> d = {'a': 0, 'a': 1, 'b': 0}
>>> d
{'a': 1, 'b': 0}
```

So you effectively lose some information when you construct your dictionary. Hence plotting from this dictionary alone is impossible (since the information isn't there).

It seems like you're using the dictionary keys as some kind of classification. Perhaps a list of tuples makes more sense in this case:

```
F_type = [('CaII', 3933.70), ('CaII', 3968.50), etc, etc]
for val in F_type:
    plt.axvline(x=val[1])
```

Comment: Got it, that makes sense.I didn't know that about dictionaries. Thank you!